# How to reuse Gradle daemon in a self-hosted Github workflow

Tags: gradle, github-actions

When I run my workflow script in Github, every time in the build step of my program that uses Gradle it says "Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 13 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details". It starts a new Gradle daemon every time instead of using an existing one. Not a big deal, but it would save a little bit of time. I'm running the workflow on one of my computers, so I can change anything in the environment the script runs in. How can I make it so it reuses a daemon that was idling? I'm guessing the one that says incompatible was the one that I used earlier to build the same exact thing, so why doesn't it just use that?

Workflow script (I'm using Windows to run it because I can't access my ubuntu servers right now):

```
name: Release

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: self-hosted

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        run: |
          git fetch
          git pull

      - name: Set up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3.13.0
        with:
          distribution: 'adopt'
          java-version: '21'

      - name: Build and test
        run: ./gradlew build

      - name: Determine version
        id: determine_version
        run: |
          Write-Output "version_num=$(./gradlew -q printVersion)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          Write-Output "version=v$version_num" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          Write-Output "$version"

      - name: Get previous version
        id: previous_version
        run: Write-Output "prev_version=$(git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Check if version has changed
        id: version_changed
        run: Write-Output "changed=${{ steps.determine_version.outputs.version != steps.previous_version.outputs.prev_version }}"  >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Generate release notes
        id: release_notes
        if: ${{ steps.version_changed.outputs.changed == 'true' }}
        run: |
          Write-Output "release_notes=$(git log $(git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))..HEAD --oneline)"  >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Build JAR file
        id: build_jar
        if: ${{ steps.version_changed.outputs.changed == 'true' }}
        run: ./gradlew build

      - name: Create release
        id: create_release
        if: ${{ steps.version_changed.outputs.changed == 'true' }}
        uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        with:
          files: build/libs/ACSecurity-${{ steps.determine_version.outputs.version_num }}.jar
          tag_name: ${{ steps.determine_version.outputs.version }}
          name: ${{ steps.determine_version.outputs.version }}
          body: |
            ${ {steps.release_notes.outputs.release_notes} }
```

What that script actually does is every time the repo receives a push, it checks if the version number in the gradle build file has changed (gradle prints the project version), then if the latest tag's name doesn't match, it creates a new release

Comment: The problem was with Windows and when I changed to Ubuntu, it works fine now. Windows is dumb. It's clunky, everything takes longer, you have to install extra stuff for things to work, there are way more problems, more viruses, the list goes on and on